# How to prevent touches passing through a UITableView contained in a custom callout view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, mkmapview

I have created a custom callout view which contains a UITableView. The callout view is a subview of the annotation view the user selects. My problem is that whenever I select a row in the table view, a touch event is correctly registered by the table view and then passed on to the map view underneath. This causes the callout view to disappear. My goal is to keep it visible after selecting a row in the table view.